# Создание простого инфоблока через API Битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс

Через phinx пытаюсь создать новый инфоблок.

```
public function up(){
        if (CModule::IncludeModule("iblock")){
        $type='typeblock';
        $SORT=500;
        $ib = new CIBlock;
        $arFields = Array(
            "ACTIVE" => 'Y',
            "NAME" => 'mynewblock',
            "CODE" => 'newblock',
            "IBLOCK_TYPE_ID" => $type,
            "SITE_ID" => 's1',
            "SORT" => $SORT,
            "DESCRIPTION_TYPE" => 'text',

        );
        $ib->Add($arFields);

        }
}
```

Миграция проходит, однако в админке и в бд ничего нового не появляется. Мб я пропустил какие-то обязательные параметры?

Comment: Научитесь __дебагать__ свой код. Проверять что сработал `if`. Затем можно открыть __мануал__ битриксовый https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblock/add.php и в блоке __Возвращаемое значение__ почитать что возвращается и сравнить с тем что возвращается у вас. Спасибо.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку. Слишком много инфы за раз приходит в голову, пока всю админку не перетыкал не нашел Type_id