# Bitrix Скрипт не работает через phinx

Tags: php, битрикс

Есть такой скрипт который сам по себе прекрасно отрабатывает.
Однако через phinx он создает только новый тип инфоблока.
 Этот тип появляется в админке не сразу, а только если я запускаю данный скрипт через браузер (с другим именем типа инфоблока) Или добавляю новый тип инфоблока через админку.
В бд записи появляются идентичные с теми какие появляются если я создаю тип инфоблока через админку.

```
public function up(){
    if (CModule::IncludeModule("iblock")){

        $blocktype="user_list3";
        $arFields = Array(
            'ID'=>$blocktype,
            'SECTIONS'=>'Y',
            'EDIT_FILE_BEFORE'=>'',
            'EDIT_FILE_AFTER'=>'',
            'IN_RSS'=>'N',
            'SORT'=>500,
            "LANG"=>Array(
                "ru"=>Array(
                    "NAME"=>"Новый тип  миргации",
                ),
                "en"=>Array(
                    "NAME"=>"New type migrations",
        )
            )
        );
        global $DB;
        $obBlocktype = new CIBlockType;
        $DB->StartTransaction();
        $res = $obBlocktype->Add($arFields);
        if(!$res)
        {
            $DB->Rollback();
            echo 'Error: '.$obBlocktype->LAST_ERROR.'<br>';
        }
        else
            $DB->Commit();
        var_dump($res->LAST_ERROR);
        var_dump($res);

    }
}
```

Comment: Криво создается тип блока. Из админки не могу сделать новый инфоблок этого типа.

Comment: После того как в совершенно другом типе инфоблока создаю новый инфоблок. Тип инфоблока со скрипта внезапно начинает работать

Comment: Ну так покажите тогда в чему подвязан ваш скрипт. Что должно его инициализировать. cli у битриксового api нет.

Comment: Потенциальный дубликат вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/867120/ - не плодите вопросы с минимальным отличием. Лучше обновите один свой вопрос. Количество вопросов никак не повышает шансы на ответ.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Создание простого инфоблока через API Битрикс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/867120/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-api-%d0%91%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%81)